# Expectation to draw all numbers from 1 to 100

Tags: expected-value

I have 100  papers each contains numbers like 
(1,2), (2,3),(3,4),..., (99,100), (100,100). I draw 
each paper and note down its numbers and return that paper.
How any times I have to draw on average to note down all 
numbers from 1,2, .., 100?

Let $X_n$ be the total  numbers on average drawn at $n$-time. 
I observed experimentally $X_{n+1}$ is around $X_n+(1-\frac{X_n}{100})2$

Comment: Do papers contain different numbers, or also twice the same number?

Comment: Papers contain all different consecutive numbers except last paper which contains (100,100).